# How do I load this array into Core Data Entity?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, csv, nsarray

Hi I am struggling to figure out how to loop through the array below and add each row into my core data entity

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
//CREATE AN ARRAY FROM CSV DOCUMENT USING CHCSVPARSER
NSError *error;
NSString *customerCSV = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CUSTOMERS" ofType:@"csv"];
NSArray *importArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:customerCSV encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",importArray);

//LOOP THROUGH CREATED ARRAY AND ADD OBJECTS TO COREDATA CUSTOMER ENTITY
Invoice_MarketAppDelegate* delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;
NSManagedObject* newCustomer;
newCustomer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Customers" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

I don't know what to do here.

```
for () {
    NSLog(@"importing Row");

}
```

Here is a log of the attributes I will be importing, provided at the command

```
 NSLog(@"%@",importArray);
```

since the csv included column names

```
(

    CONTACTNAME,
    PHONE,
    COMPANYNAME,
    NOTES
),
```

Answer (score 4):

If all you have is 4 objects, don't bother looping you can simply -

If you have a sub class of Customers you can use:

```
 newCustomer.contactName = [importArray objectAtIndex:0];//change it to the correct index, and correct property name
 newCustomer.phone = [importArray objectAtIndex:1];
 //....And so on
```

else you will need to use

```
 [newCustomer objectForKey:@"contactName"] = [importArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

**BUT**

If you have many properties in your CSV you can set an other array of the keys in your entity and  -

```
     for(NSUInteger i=0;i<[importArray count];i++){
       [newCustomer objectForKey:[keysArry objectAtIndex:i]] = [importArray objectAtIndex:i];  
     }
```

**Better sometimes**

A better way to handle this, ecpaciely if you have many properties is to use -

```
 //1. crate a dictionary from your CSV with keys that are similar to your entity property names.
 NSDictionary *csvDictinary = []//set your dictionary.
 //2.get all the property names from your customers entity
 NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSEntityDescription
                             entityForName:@"Costumer"
                             inManagedObjectContext:self] attributesByName];
//3. set the properties to your entity
for (NSString *attr in attributes) {
    [Costumer setValue:[csvDictinary valueForKey:attr] forKey:attr];
}
```

**EDIT**
To sub class your entity:

1. select the entity in the model editor.
2. in Xcode menu select Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass.
3. import or @class your new subclass when you want to refer it.

**BTW**

1. Subclass your entities - it will make your life easier and will cause better performance.
2. Your entity name should be  -"Customer" in singular, as it hold only 1 customer.

Comment: Ok sorry I may have simplified my question a little too much just to make it easier to understand. I stated that I only have four column names (Phone, CompanyName, ContactName & Notes) in truth I have about 30 columns and over 400 rows. It's really a customer list which I am trying to import, so I think i will use your "for" method. I am getting errors with it however. In the 1st line I get `redefinition of i` & `expected ; in 'for' statement specifier`. In the 2nd line `receiver type NSManagedObject for instance message does not declare a method with selector: 'objectForKey:` Can you help me?

Comment: Ok i fixed the first like it should be `for(NSUInteger i=0;i<[importArray count];i++){` I would edit it but I don't have enough XP to edit. How can i fix the second line error and subclass the entity as you suggest?